# How do I Unit Test an EJB Webservice (Glassfish v2)?

Tags: java, web-services, unit-testing, glassfish

I am currently having issues because the WebServiceContext is not initialised, obviously because the unit test is not within the EJB container. Is there anyway to manually create a WebServiceContext for testing purposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that actually testing the EJB within a container and making it run properly across platforms and tools (e.g. code coverage) is quite difficult at best and really slow in terms of execution performance.

Rather than executing the unit test in a container, you can focus more on the business logoc side and manually inject the needed components and run the @PostConstruct manually as part of your unit test harness then test your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenEJB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openejb/) for that. Take a look at this stackoverflow thread:

- [Test @Webservice EJBs with WebServiceContext (using OpenEJB?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175879/test-webservice-ejbs-with-webservicecontext-using-openejb)

Answer (score 0):

You can also unit test in GlassFish Server 3 (it's backwards compatible with Java EE 5).