# Test @Webservice EJB with WebServiceContext (Arquillian)

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, jboss-arquillian

I am having the same problem from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175879/test-webservice-ejbs-with-webservicecontext-using-openejb), but my environment uses Arquillian for testing instead of OpenEJB.

My problem is that I get the user Principal name programmatically and, although this works perfectly in the running application, this call fails with the following exception during test execution:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.jboss.ws.common.injection.ThreadLocalAwareWebServiceContext.getWebServiceContext(ThreadLocalAwareWebServiceContext.java:88)
    at org.jboss.ws.common.injection.ThreadLocalAwareWebServiceContext.getUserPrincipal(ThreadLocalAwareWebServiceContext.java:74)
```

Is there any way I can make this work? By mocking the WebServiceContext or something...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem while testing today. From what I could see, the Handlers don't have view of the state of the Web Service. If this is something specific to Arquillian, I'm not sure.

However, this isn't a problem as the `SOAPMessageContext` parameter to the `handleMessage` method extends the `MessageContext` interface, so you should be able to access almost anything you need directly from the `SOAPMessageContext` without needing access to the `WebServiceContext`. The only obvious exception I could see was the user principal.

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext soapMessageContext) {
  String value = (String) soapMessageContext.get("myKey");
}
```

Just one additional comment, if you want to put an object into the `MessageContext` map and also want it available inside your endpoint, make sure to set the scope:

```
soapMessageContext.put("myKey", "someValue");
soapMessageContext.setScope("myKey", MessageContext.Scope.APPLICATION);
```